# How to make "action, based on user input" code look prettier?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, input

For example, if user inputs `a`, program should print `x`, if user inputs `b`, program should print `y`, if user types `c`, program should print `z`. And so on.

Is there a way to make it without `if elif elif elif elif elif...`? I mean... It doesn't look right to me, there should be a better way to do so. Right?

Comment: You can use switch case if you want

Comment: have you considered using a dicitonary?

Comment: If it's only mapping one string to another, use a dict: `{'a': 'x', ...}`. If it's any more complicated than that, `elif` is basically it…

Comment: @Nitin Please demonstrate. Note: [tag:python]…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionary will be the best for that

```
dc = {'a': 'x', 'b': 'y', 'c': 'z'}
a = input("input a character") #input c
print(dc.get(a, None))
```

Output

```
'z'
```

With the dictionary, you can map easily the desired output base on the user input.
In the get method of the dictionary, you can put a default value in case the dictionary doesn't have a map for a specific character.